# How does Visual Studio C/C++ work with remote device?

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio, ssh

I'm writing C code for remote device (actually an Orange Pi Zero with [Armbian Legacy Server -- Debian Jessie](https://www.armbian.com/orange-pi-zero/)). And just to be clear, all compilation is occurring on the Linux remote device. I'm trying to write C code programs for the device.  Lets start [simple](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/rpii/cintro.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("\nHello World!!\n");
    int number = 15;
    printf("15 = %d\n", number);
    return 0; 
}
```

Now I know I can SSH to the device, login, create a helloWorld.c file, and paste the code there (via `nano helloWorld.c`).  I can then compile the code on the device with

```
 gcc helloWorld.c -o helloWorld
```

I can then run the executable via the bash / shell command from the SSH console:

```
 ./helloWorld
```

Works great.  So far, so good.  A shell editor is fine for small files, but when things get complicated, that's a pain.  I'd like to have a copy of what I'm writing on my desktop.   So I'm trying to use Microsoft Visual Studio (Community Edition 2015, with update 3) for doing this.  I'm following the tutorial at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/  This tutorial seems relatively up to date, kinda, sorta.  I load the [Visual C++ for Linux Development extension](https://aka.ms/vslinuxext).  One item of note is I am NOT using the purchased package from VisualGDB.com.  Instead I download the following dependencies to the remote device via:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server g++ gdb gdbserver
```

I create a project in Visual Studio, via Templates --> Visual C++ --> Cross Platform --> Linux, and select Empty Project.  I load up all the SSH login info to Visual Studio.  I can build/compile the project. When I do that, and then SSH into the remote Linux device, I can see the addition of a `projects` folder at my root.

```
 projects directory
      helloWorld directory
           bin directory
                ARM directory
                     Debug directory
                          helloWorld.out file  <--- ./helloWorld.out works!
           obj directory
                ARM directory
                     Debug directory
                          helloWorld.o file
           helloWorld.c file
```

I can debug the project by stepping thru the code from my desktop. I can watch variables, see things great in debug mode. There are a couple of things I just don't understand.

1) When I 'run' the code from the desktop Visual Studio, I can't see any output. The output window is just blank. (I can SSH to the Linux server bin directory, then run `./helloWorld.out` and see things just fine in the SSH interpreter screen.) Hint: If I can step thru code successfully remotely shouldn't I be able to see output remotely? Should I be seeing output in Visual Studio?

2) Its not clear on how I add addition link resources for compilation from Visual Studio.  (If I was SSH'd to the device I'd just type `gcc helloWorld.c -o helloWorld -lwiringPi` to add the additional resources.) How do you add additional link resources in Visual Studio?

Comment: On the blog you linked, there is information about a *Console Window*, did you try it? (Debug > Linux Console). To add extra "link resources", you probably want to go Property > Linker.

Comment: Ouch.  There was a lot in that portion of the blog entry that doesn't match current Visual Studio releases. I totally skipped over the Console Window thing.  You are absolutely correct. That works great.  Please convert your note over to an answer so I can accept?

Comment: To begin with, there is no such thing as Visual Studio C/C++. Visual Studio is mostly a C++ compiler. The support for C is completely outdated and lacking.

Comment: @Lundin  I appreciate the comment. I didn't realize that. Here, though, we're doing all compilation on the target Linux device. We're just using Visual Studio as a handy editor / debugger tool for a SSH session to a remote device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some review, I've discovered the answers to my two questions posted above.

1) Console Window
    From top menu, Debug --> Linux Console

2) Linked Resources.

First ensure libraries are correctly loaded and compiled on the remote Linux Device.  In my case I've been using General Purpose Input / Output (GPIO) WiringPi library for Raspberry Pi, available [here](http://wiringpi.com/) or [here](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi). For the WiringOp library for Orange Pi, check [here](https://github.com/zhaolei/WiringOP).

To add a library reference in Visual Studio start at the top menu, Project --> Properties -–> Linker -–> Input. In the block entitled “Library Dependencies” you will add the library name, in my case ‘wiringPi’.  This generates the command line that tells the system to look for that library on the remote device. The files needed are actually located on the remote Linux device at /usr/local/lib (normally xxx.so files).

One other note of interest:  If you don't have the correct libraries compiled on the target Linux remote device, the error message you get in visual studio when you try to run the program is somewhat cryptic.  You will see “fatal error: wiringPi.h: No such file or directory."  Its not entirely clear that message is referring to missing content on the remote device.

Note: Here's [a write up on using Visual Studio with a C program for a Raspberry Pi.](http://dogfeatherdesign.com/debugging-cc-code-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-visual-studio/)